# UK Refugee travel document (blue color) and visas for France

Tags: visas, uk, europe, refugees

I have a UK blue refugee travel document. Do I need a visa for entry to France?

My original nationality is Nigeria, and I am confused about the eligibility for the 90 days visa free entry following the brexit travel update

Answer (score 3):

France is not part anymore of the [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/-/council-of-europe-european-agreement-on-the-abolition-of-visas-for-refugees-ets-no-031-translations), so

[France Visa site](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/visa-wizard) states :

> You need a visa.

Comment: Strictly speaking France *suspended* this in 1986, but that was long enough ago to now be seen as permanent. (The UK did something similar in 2003)